# Linking Subversion Post Commit with Trac

Tags: svn, x86, trac, bitnami

I have installed Trac through the BitNami Trac stack.
The installation went really smooth without any issues.
By default it has installed in the following location

**C:\Documents and Settings\Modi\BitNami Trac Stack projects**

and

**C:\Documents and Settings\Modi\BitNami Trac Stack repository**

**Q1.      How do i add / change the default project repository ?**

**Q2.      How will i know the TRAC_ENV,PYTHON_PATH and TRAC_PATH variable values considering the fact i installed using BitNami and i completely have NO idea about the silent installation of python files ?**

Now inorder for me to integrate the commit to the repository (SVN) 
to Trac and close the bugs that were noted in the SVN Comment, how should i go ahead with the post-commit-hooks.

i.e If i entered in the SVNLog, the following comment : fixed for the issue #123
(where **#123** is a ticket in Trac). I should be able to browse to the particular Trac ticket upon clicking the #123, in the svn log.

Has anyone done this ?

If yes, Is there a clear document which explains to perform the above mentioned steps.?

Sorry if i sound too dumb :) Please excuse

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first tried to install Trac via the Bitnami installer and I found it difficult to customize and update.  I had an easier time installing Trac manually inside a Linux system that was running in a virtual machine.  I'm afraid I can't answer your first two questions, as those were some of the same problems that I ran up against.  I was also unable to find very much documentation on the Bitnami Trac stack (I could find docs on Bitnami in general, but not on a specific stack).  There are lots of instructions available on Trac's site regarding how to install it on various platforms.  If you need to customize your installation beyond the default that Bitnami sets up, I would recommend reading through the instructions and considering removing the Bitnami stack and doing a fresh manual install.  You can find setup instructions [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/twickers/archive/2010/02/08/137853.aspx), [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnWindows), and [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CookBook/Installation#OnWindows), and there are detailed step-by-step instructions [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/attachment/wiki/TracOnWindows/Step_by_Step-installation-manual.txt).  Some of those guides reference old versions of Apache, Python, etc. so you may want to grab a more current version (when available).

[This forum thread](http://bitnami.org/forums/forums/trac/topics/pre-and-post-commit-hook-scripts) may also be relevant to your situation.

Regarding your other questions: yes, Trac should automatically convert text like `#123` in commit messages to links to the appropriate ticket.  This is automatic, you don't have to configure anything to make this happen.  If you also want Trac to use this information to (for example) close tickets, take a look at the instructions given [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFaq#can-trac-automatically-update-a-ticket-when-i-commit-a-changeset).

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Even I was considering the option of freshly installing the Trac,Python and SQLite. 1 up for the helpful links